# Реально ли подключить субтитры при потоковом воспроизведении? (hls, m3u8)

Tags: потоки-данных, ffmpeg, online-video, hls, m3u

Пытаюсь создать поток, в котором по средствам будут воспроизводиться дорожки из конвертируемого файла (в моем случае MKV to m3u8). В данный момент получается переключаться между несколькими разрешениями, и даже выбирать аудиодорожку, но субтитры не видит вообще.

ffprobe исходного файла:
https://paste2.org/czUePDPj

Раскладываю на дорожки и создаю для каждый свой .m3u8

```
ffmpeg -i '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/Rick.mkv' \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset:v superfast -strict -2 -s 426x240   -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick240p -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/Rick240p_%d.ts'      '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/Rick240p.m3u8' \
-map 0:a:0 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick_ru -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_ru_%d.aac'        '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_ru.m3u8' \
-map 0:a:1 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick_en -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_en_%d.aac'        '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_en.m3u8' \
-map 0:s:0 suben.vtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list en -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_en_%d.vtt'  '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_en.m3u8' \
-map 0:s:1 subru.vtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list ru -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_ru_%d.vtt'  '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_ru.m3u8'
```

Создаю главный .m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="Russian",LANGUAGE="ru",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="RickTrack_ru.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=NO,URI="RickTrack_en.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Russian",DEFAULT=YES,FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="ru",URI="sub_ru.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=NO,FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="sub_en.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=928000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=480x270,AUDIO="audio",SUBTITLES="subs"
Rick240p.m3u8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решилось все просто: расширение файла с субтитрами не влияет на их работу, а именно полный файл с субтитрами с расширением .vtt работает по аналогии с .m3u8. Кроме того, необходимо указать type="application/octet-stream"
В конечном варианте с этими изменениями у меня заработало:

```
 <video id="stream_video_tag" width="800" height="600" controls>
      <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      <track src="sub_en.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" kind="subtitles" 
    type="application/octet-stream">
      <track src="sub_ru.vtt" srclang="ru" label="Russian" kind="subtitles" 
    type="application/octet-stream">
    </video>
```